# Laravel localize url helper

Tags: php, laravel, localization, routes, helper

I need to localize my website. I am using this package: https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization 
My route group is:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale()], function()
{
Route::get('/garage', ['as' => 'garage', 'uses' => 'GarageController@garage']);
//OTHER ROUTES
});
```

And i want to localize link to this route. If i am using

```
href="{{ route('garage') }}
```

everything is ok, link looks like "www.example.com/locale/garage".
But if i am using

```
href="{{ url('/garage') }}
```

my localization doesn't work, link looks like "www.example.com/garage".
Is there some way to localize links made with URL helper?

Comment: href="{{ url(LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale().'/garage') }}"

Comment: @Calin yes, this will work, thx, but i have few hundreds link in code :( Is there smth more elegant than this way?

Comment: As far as I know, not without using named routes.

Answer (score 1):

LaravelLocalization package includes a middleware object to redirect all non-localized routes to the corresponding "localized".

So, if a user navigates to `http://www.example.com/test` and the system has this middleware active and 'en' as the current locale for this user, it would redirect him automatically to `http://www.example.com/en/test`.

To active this functionality go to `app/Http/Kernel.php` and add these classes in `protected $routeMiddleware = []` at the beginning and then in your routes file bring these changes:

```
Route::group([
'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath' ]
], function()
{
Route::get('/garage', ['as' => 'garage', 'uses' => 'GarageController@garage']);
//OTHER ROUTES
});
```

And your problem will be solved.